# How can I fix error in linear mixed model?

Tags: r, lme4

I am running a linear mixed model.
I don't know why I have the following error.
The fixed effects are `ageroup` and `Phase`.
The random effect is `username`.

```r
mixed.lmer <- lmer(compound ~ Phase_2 + agegroup + (1|username), data = df23)
summary(mixed.lmer)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(data = df23, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, formula = compound ~  :
> variable lengths differ (found for 'Phase_2')

The data have some `NA`s in `agegroup` and `score`, since not all the usernames have `score` values in all Phases(1,2,3).

```
> str(df23)
tibble [941,448 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ username  : chr [1:941448] "____________bug" "____________bug" "____________bug" "____________Nia" ...
 $ Phase_2   : num [1:941448] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ agegroup  : chr [1:941448] "YA" NA NA "YA" ...
 $ mean_score: num [1:941448] 0.735 NA NA 0.67 NA ...
```

```
structure(list(username = c("mimi__ramos", "_LucyParker", "bttrhmsndgrdns", 
"chicken__lady", "TheSolape", "theg0ldengirl", "RoyalFlushpokr", 
"svnsettown", "Abbeyleighsmith", "12voltman60", "MartiTweetsTV", 
"alienrobotXperC", "ChanIncognito", "WoW_Chicken_", "KayJ12", 
"Abhisheksing164", "tayyy_712", "wiinterwiidow", "ngyntlinh", 
"theonlysesmo", "LenairH", "ImomoTimipa", "ayjmnssigan", "TheEdiCorona", 
"makeyoubillions", "jamescat79", "Jro9902", "_prettybrwn_", "LilDisFan", 
"yoavkaufman", "FenrirCe", "LaVidaBoricua", "KHoey3000", "Jessica_Wicket", 
"spha305", "selenasgardenn", "ListElaine", "emilyannleivas", 
"dojae1s", "tpwk_aiyana", "davidalmond86", "mmahalwy", "danielandjay", 
"ullyabigail", "pawncrackers", "ibsroyalty", "coolbhopz", "PolsSteph", 
"practicalbob", "Soccermom1714", "jodimediocre", "_RayGervais", 
"A_Omodu", "EdoCrypto2", "nathan_hauk", "asl3676", "beckytaylorgill", 
"lalisaglowz", "pinkpluswhite__", "a_time_in_grey", "Ruth_fielamor", 
"Besaid_Aurochs", "FlannaganSonia", "mo_onstarry", "thisisnayeon", 
"emnelder", "Kate_Travels", "pizza_fucker69", "alexrubner", "kissphoria", 
"AquafabaMcGee", "jahintheshammer", "Kate_in_Guelph", "tatertooots", 
"Gillbaba302", "guillotines_rus", "Sara_Rossetti4", "Sentry_23", 
"imashvelasco", "chinifromdabloc", "seeonbothsidez", "IamShainaJaye", 
"ggrovyle", "MsMicheleNicole", "sire_gabriel", "thafoodist", 
"AudryFerraris", "aksainsbury", "alyakhairina_", "csmitroyalfan", 
"richardtheap", "jkhuggins", "nogumbofornazis", "Filemon_Fly", 
"LiamBeh98157012", "ayjmnssigan", "P_Luxolo", "simmonneee", "GivHerMigraines", 
"__ninarose"), compound = c(-0.765, 0.743, 0.1901, 0, 0, 0.743, 
0.2732, -0.2263, 0.3612, -0.2263, 0.9906, 0, 0.4404, 0, 0.5106, 
-0.7533, -0.2942, 0.7351, -0.9505, 0, 0.755, -0.4886, 0.9266, 
0, 0.7199, -0.4959, 0, -0.0772, 0.3818, 0.8074, 0, -0.34, 0, 
-0.5983, 0.6124, 0.4648, 0.7717, 0.6369, 0, 0.3612, -0.8176, 
0.9134, 0.6239, 0.7667, 0.9817, 0.6988, 0.296, 0.2732, 0.431, 
-0.5057, -0.4184, 0.936, 0.7346, 0, 0.6808, -0.34, 0.128, 0, 
0, 0, 0.6249, 0, 0.2905, 0.891, 0, 0.6597, 0.5916, -0.4215, -0.0798, 
-0.0258, 0.5684, -0.8122, 0.5193, 0.7579, 0, 0.6249, 0.8225, 
-0.0926, 0, 0.3515, 0.6124, 0, 0, 0.7269, -0.6679, 0.8622, -0.8126, 
0, 0.2263, 0.4588, 0, -0.683, 0, -0.3415, -0.3182, 0.9819, 0, 
-0.2732, -0.453, 0), agegroup = c("YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "MA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "OA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "OA", 
"MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", 
"YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "MA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "MA", "MA", "YA", 
"YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA", "YA"), Phase_2 = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I used the below code to generate df23. It seems that this code does not generate right "agegroup"

```
df23 <- data_d %>%
  group_by(username, agegroup, Phase_2,) %>%
  summarise(mean_score = mean_(compound), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  complete(username, Phase_2)
```

find("Phase_2") shows

```
> find("Phase_2")
[1] "df23" "df23" "df23" "data" "data"
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with `str(df23)` please ; perhaps you have a variable `Phase` in your global environment and not in the data which is getting used??

Comment: @user20650 Thanks, I added.

Comment: okay, so the variable is called `Phase_2` not `Phase`. Can you try it with `lmer(score ~ Phase_2 + agegroup + (1|username), data = df23)`

Comment: @user20650.  Yes, I used Phase_2, sorry for the typo in the demo.mixed.lmer <- lmer(compound ~ Phase_2 + agegroup + (1|username), data = df23)
Error in model.frame.default(data = df23, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, formula = compound ~  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Phase_2')

Comment: I second @user2650's first comment; you probably have variables in your local environment (did you use the `attach()` function ??).  Please try `find("Phase_2")` and edit your question to include the results ...

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with an example that replicates this. Could we have a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker dput added

Comment: @user20650 dput added

Comment: You haven't given us enough  data to reproduce yet.  When I set `df23` to the `dput()` you've given and run `mixed.lmer <- lmer(mean_score ~ Phase_2 + agegroup + (1|username), data = df23)`, I get an error about contrast levels because once non-complete cases are dropped, only observations with `agegroup=="YA"` are left.

Comment: Obviously you can't post a million-row tibble, but we really need something reproducible: what if you use `set.seed(101); r <- df23[complete.cases(df23),]; example <- r[sample(nrow(r), size=50, replace=FALSE), ]`; does that reproduce? (What about the Qs we asked about `find()` and `attach()` ... ?)

Comment: I think it may be time for "*Have you tried turning it off and on again?*".  Restart R in a new session without loading a previous workspace, and then see if you still get the error but keeping your code as minimal as possible (i.e. read in data then run lmer code, and definitely no attach)

Comment: @user20650 edited original data and code to generate df23

Comment: **Still not reproducible**. Your `df23` doesn't include a `mean_score` component. If I use `compound` as the response variable, I get a rank-deficiency warning, but the model runs. I'm going to have to give up on this soon ...

Comment: @BenBolk erdited original data and code to generate df23

Comment: Thanks for adding data @Zhen but can you make sure that the data you add relates to the code shown in your lmer call. As there are differences in names it really does make it very difficult to work out what is happening (and its already difficult). As Ben has said, can you create a subset of data (similar to what you have done) but make sure that the same variables are in it that are in the lmer function -- and please do indicate if you still get the same error for that small subset.  Ps as earlier requested what did `find("Phase_2")` return please?

Comment: @user20650 Thanks. I fixed the code. It seems that I used the wrong way to generate "agegroup" using group by function.

Comment: Thanks. The values returned from `find("Phase_2")` looks a bit weird; I don't know wht you would get repeat values. Did you try [restarting & not loading previous workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780887/how-can-i-fix-error-in-linear-mixed-model#comment119807144_67780887)

Comment: @user20650 Thanks, it seems that I did not generate the right agegroup with this code df23 <- data_d %>%
  group_by(username, agegroup, Phase_2,) %>%
  summarise(mean_score = mean_(compound), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  complete(username, Phase_2)   Only YA, is here, no MA and OA.